# Missing comment in a SO Jobs ad

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I saw this Stack Overflow Jobs advertisement just now:

[image: Job ad]

Something small is bothering me; the bottom line is not a comment.

As a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) developer, I strongly believe we need to add a `//` to it.